# Отличие модели от миграции в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование, model, миграция

В чем отличие модели от миграции в Laravel? Как я понял: создание миграции - это создание структуры таблицы базы данных, а модель - это все данные внутри таблицы. Распишите подробно.

Comment: без подчеркивания не поймете?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев я просто очень хочу знать (получить хороший, **достаточно подробный** ответ). Просто во всех ресурсах, которые я смотрел, понятие модели и миграции очень **сбивчиво** (**достаточно плотно** к друг другу) описаны.

Comment: если вопросы будут - задавайте их под ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Миграции

> создание миграции - это создание структуры таблицы базы данных

Это заблуждение.

Миграция - это класс описывающий действия, которые приводят базу данных из состояния `A` в состояние `B` и при необходимости обратно.
Миграции это **очень грубо говоря** - попытка сделать аналог коммитов и системы контроля версий для базы данных.

Самый распространенный кейс использования миграций следующий:

У вас есть несколько сред исполнения

- среда разработки
- среда тестирования
- производственная среда (production)

Вместе с этим имеются другие условия:

- Кодовая база распространяется через репозиторий системы контроля версий.
- Версии кодовой базы на них отличаются друг от друга.
- Различные версии кодовой базы требуют различное состояние базы данных.
- Нужно иметь возможность быстро, а в идеале автоматически привести состояние базы данных в соответствии с нужной версий кодовой базы

Чтобы обеспечить это используют миграции, которые сопровождают зафиксированные изменения в кодовой базе и производят соответствующие изменения в базе данных.

**Пример того как это происходит:**

1. Разработчик решает задачу в среде разработке на собственной машине.
2. В ходе решения задачи ему необходимо произвести в базе данных изменения
3. Разработчик фиксирует эти изменения в миграции.
4. Разработчик коммитит изменения в кодовой базе и миграцию вместе с ними.
5. Разработчик пушит эти изменения в репозиторий, после чего это его ветку сливают с другими ветками в которых параллельно велась разработка другими разработчиками.
6. Тестовая среда получает изменения из этой ветки и применяет все необходимые миграции
7. Тестировщики тестируют все и говорят что все ок. В идеале должны быть еще unit-тесты и авто-тесы морды но их мы опустим
8. Менеджеры одобряют релиз и он идёт на производственную среду.
9. Все изменения сливаются в основную ветку
10. На производственной среде обновляют ветку.
11. На производственной среде применяют миграции, чтобы база данных соответствовала актуальной кодовой базе.
12. Происходит непредвиденное и на продакшене все находят критический баг, который проявился только в данных из производственной среде
13. Никто не паникует:
    13.1 Миграции откатываются
    13.2 Версия кодовой базы тоже откатывается
14. Виновные наказываются и идут править баги
15. А производственная среда работает как будто ничего и не было...Да на прошлой версии, но живая и невредимая. А это главное

#### Модель

А модель - это класс описывающий модель предметной области.
И это понятие чуть шире чем просто класс, который будет маппится на какую-то таблицу в БД, хотя очень часто применяется именно в этом контексте

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138378/discussion-on-answer-by--------laravel).